# google maps - if zoom level is equal to max zoom do something?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Working on Google Maps v3 and also using the markerclusterplus.js for clustering of markers ([link](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/)).

As it stands everything works correctly.  Now what I want to do is show an infowindow on click of the markerClusterer if its maxZoom has been reached.  As it stands I have maxZoom set to 15.  The idea is if someone clicks on a cluster it will keep zooming until it is no longer a cluster and shows multiple markers OR it hits the maxZoom (15) and it still a cluster of multiple markers.  If it hits the maxZoom there could be any number of markers contained in the cluster all of which can be retrieved with `c.getMarkers());`  I can then use the array of returned markers to show an infowindow that has information about the entire group.

**My question is...** is `if(map.getZoom() == 15)` a legitimate test to know when a cluster has reached its zoom level?  15 is what I set maxZoom too, but can there be a case when it can only zoom to 16,17,20, etc?  If so, my logic will not work and the infowindow would not be shown in those cases.... is there a way to test if the map cannot be zoomed any further?

For some reason I thought that certain parts of the world had a limited zoom level.  One part might be able to be zoomed to 4 while another might only be able to be zoomed to 20.  This is what is bringing my question up.  The whole point of this is to show information about multiple markers who are either the exact location or are so close in proximity they might as well be.

**Cluster logic :**

```
// var map = my google map
// var markers = my array of markers

// set mc options
var mcOptions = {
    gridSize: 50,
    maxZoom: 15,
    title: 'Multiple Users'
};

//set marker clusterer
var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

//markercluster listener
google.maps.event.addListener(markerCluster, "click", function (c) {                
    console.log('zoom is : '+map.getZoom());
    console.log('zoom on click is : '+markerCluster.getZoomOnClick());
    console.log('array of markers is : '+c.getMarkers());

    if(map.getZoom() == 15)
    {
        //display infowindow with all marker info
    }
});
```

`markerCluster.getZoomOnClick();` returns true regardless if the maxZoom level has been reached so I don't think this will be useful.

`map.getZoom();` on the other hand will show the current zoom level so if I know the zoom level can always reach at least 15 everything should work fine, but that is my question... will it?

Answer (score 1):

`getZoomOnClick()` returns the static property `zoomOnClick_`, which defines the default behavior of zooming on click. It won't change according to the zoom level.

For your use case, you could do

```
if(map.getZoom()>= c.getMaxZoom()) {
  // display infowindow
}
```

Keep in mind that the `markerCluster` instance extends from `google.maps.OverlayView` which doesn't detect click events.

In this case, this will work only because the ClusterIcon.prototype has a DOM listener declared on its click event, programatically triggering the MarkerClusterer click event.

```
ClusterIcon.prototype.onAdd = function () {    
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "click", function (e) {
    var mc = cClusterIcon.cluster_.getMarkerClusterer();

    google.maps.event.trigger(mc, "click", cClusterIcon.cluster_);
  };
};
```

I mention this because if you try and add other mouse related listeners on the markerClusterer, you'll find out they don't get triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  My question still stands though.  Is it possible for a location on the map to have 'lowest zoom level' above 15?  I'm not worried about the code or how to do it... I just need to know if that logic will always hold true... in other words if ANY location can always be zoomed in further than level 15.

Comment: That wasn't your main question. However, it is my understanding that in the worst case scenario you'll still be able to zoom past 15, it just won't load more detailed tiles but instead will keep zooming on the existing ones.

Comment: It was my only question if you look at my post.  You can't zoom past 15 when I have maxZoom set to 15 so that is not an issue.  I was going to use zoom 15 to trigger showing the clustered info if it is a cluster... I want to know if certain parts of the map can only zoom to say 16, 17, etc... in which case my zoom 15 condition would never be met and the clustered info would never be shown.

Comment: if you can zoom to 16 or 17 then the condition "greater or equal than 15" would be met. If you declare a maxZoom in your map instance (as opposed to declaring it in your markerClusterer instance) then you won't be able to zoom past 15. Whatever the case, there's no way to query google maps to know how detailed the imagery is for a given location.

Comment: I had that backwards... if the highest zoom a certain map view could go was less than 15 then the condition would not be met.  The whole point is when you get to a certain zoom level and it is still clustered you can pretty much assume the markers are basically in the same location or not far apart.  Which is then where I would show all the marker details of the cluster on click in the infowindow.

Comment: I can't use "less than or equal to 15" in this sense.  Say the map opens (with fit bounds) at a zoom of 4 or something.  Over in Florida there is a cluster of 300.  Using that condition I would be loading all 300 marker details in the infowindow on click... whereas if I just do so on zoom 15 the cluster would be much more dialed down and maybe it was only 5 or is no longer a cluster for that matter.  Hopefully you get what I am saying.